# C# SQL, Server, Data Grid View: How to handle a Master Table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Currently, I have multiple Slave tables that when I add to them I just Make 2 separate queries and post to both, the selected slave table and a master table.

I was skimming through my application and realized I had a lot of essentially duplicate code because of my method. I really want to change this to make minimal connections to my database.

Note: I have to have a slaves data grid view depending on which slave table is chosen in the application.

So instead of using mass amounts of SQL inserts/updates/selects, I was thinking about methods such as pulling all the information from all the slave tables on load and using XML to populate the Master Table... But I don't feel this is efficient.

To explain my current Functionality:
Text Fields get inserted into Both Slave and Master Tables
Master Table inserts selected information on other chosen slave tables.

My Goal is to have a Muti-Slave table effect information on the Master and information change on the Slave Tables from the Master.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to Normalize your tables. You can create Master Table which contains a Primary Key, and accordingly make Transaction tables based on your requirements containing the Foreign Key to the Master Table. 
That will help you to store your values into corresponding (slave) tables and will also reduce redundancy of data if any.

Comment: I've already done that. I know what PK and FK does but I'm not understanding how it does it. So I have a PK in my Slave table and a FK in my Master Table, but I'm not understanding how keys stop the redundancy. Currently when I put something in a slave table.. Nothing populates in my Master Table and I manually insert into the master

Comment: Ideally you should create a PK in your master table and corresponding FK in the slave tables, thats how normalization works. Also, you will have to use joins to access more than one table.